# How can I display failed test on cucumber report?

Tags: javascript, testing, cucumber, nightwatch.js

**Hi guys,**
I am using nightwatch VRT and cucumber to do some visual regression tests.
But when a comparison of two images has failed (the baseline image and test image), it does not show that on cucumber report; it is always displayed as a passed test.

**P.S :**
=> I am using "verify" to take screen shots, for example:   ***.verify.screenshotIdenticalToBaseline(textArea1, 'Text Area ', {threshold: 0}, 'VRT complete.')***
Because when I use "assert" and he found a difference between the two images, he does not continue testing (he skips all the next tests).
Can anyone help please? I want it to continue tests and also show the error on the report :)

This is an example of a function :

```
 Test2(){
              var radioButtonLink = '//a[@id="RadioButton"]';
              var RadioButton = '//div[@title="Personne physique"]//span';
              var image = '//span[@class="picto-up-vert-small"]';
              var EmojiRBtn = '//div[@class="doc_example"][3]//div[@class="ca_checkbox_main"]//*[contains(text(), "Activer/Désactiver")]';

              return this
                   .waitForElementPresent('@Frame', 1000,'iframe is found')
                   .getAttribute('@Frame', 'id', function(result) {
                     var iframe_id = result.value;             
                     var iframe_CCV =this.frame(iframe_id); 
                         iframe_CCV
                          .waitForElementVisible(radioButtonLink, 500, 'lien radio button visible')
                          .click(radioButtonLink)             
                   })  
                  
                   .getAttribute('@FrameContent', 'id', function(result) {
                    var iframe_content_id = result.value;            
                    var iframe_content =this.frame(iframe_content_id); 
                      iframe_content
                        .waitForElementVisible(RadioButton, 1000,'radio button is found')
                        .click(RadioButton)

                        .waitForElementVisible(image, 1000,'image emoji is found')
                        .assert.screenshotIdenticalToBaseline(image, 'image Emoji', {threshold: 0}, 'VRT complete.')
                        
                        .waitForElementVisible(EmojiRBtn, 1000,'radio button emoji is found')
                        .click(EmojiRBtn)
                        .pause(1000)
                        .assert.screenshotIdenticalToBaseline(image, 'image Emoji after click', {threshold: 0}, 'VRT complete.')

                      })
          }
```

Comment: Please post the code of your `assertions`. `Assertion` needs to be individual for each test but it seems you haven't written in that way.

Comment: Actually i have more than one assertion for each test

Comment: Please add that code of that assertion

Comment: i edited my post .

Comment: What cucumber reports you are using?

Comment: "@cucumber/cucumber": "^7.0.0-rc.0",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^5.4.0",

Comment: Suppose verfication fails in `verify.screenshotIdenticalToBaselineHave` then can you try by adding the explicit message using `scenario.attach('test data goes here');`

Comment: should i replace verify..... by this line scenario.attach('test data goes here');  ?????

Comment: If verify fails then use this line. Hope it should work just try and see.

Comment: it does not show anything , the report is still showing test passed (even if it is not)

Comment: Even added message also not displaying?

Comment: No nothing at all